# My ng-repeat is not working! AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

## HTML File:##

```
<html ng-app = "TM">
<h1> Requested Businesses </h1>
<form class="form">
<body ng-controller = "appController">
  <table class="col-xs-12">
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>BusinessName</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

 <h1 ng-repeat= "item in protocolList">
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.requesterMail}}</td>
        <td>{{item.business_name}}</td>
```

> > Doesn't display anything in my html view :(

## Angular Controller:##

```
angular.module('TM', ['AppRoutes']).controller('appController', function($scope, $http,$location){

   $http({
    method: 'GET',
     url: '../businessreq',
     }).then(function(data) { 
    $scope.protocolList= data.data;
    console.log($scope.protocolList);       

});  

});
```

> > The console prints the protocolList Correctly

Comment: Change `h1` to `table` tag

Comment: Remove white spaces before/after '='

Comment: you cant use ngrepeat inside h1 tag use instead tr also you can use css to change the style inside the tr to change the text size

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thanks that's it

Comment: @Geomorillo Yea that's the answer

Comment: Thanks you saved my life guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a h1 between `td` elements. Place your `ng-repeat` in the `tr`, remove your h1 and it should work.